# getting network id from ip address & subnetmask

Tags: bash, shell, networking, scripting

I am trying to learn some shell scripting and I though it would be a nice way to combine it with my ccna study. So I am writing a simple script that scans some network devices based upon a ip address and a subnetmask provided by the user. To determine the network a host belongs to I use the following lines of code, but it keeps getting me errors.

```
read -p "Geef een IP-adres op "  i
read -p "Geef een subnetmask op "  s

IFS=. read -r i1 i2 i3 i4 <<< $i
IFS=. read -r m1 m2 m3 m4 <<< $s

ip=`printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n" $i1 $i2 $i3 $i4`
mask=`printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n" $m1 $m2 $m3 $m4`

#bepaal netwerk id
id=`printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n" "$((i1 & m1))" "$((i2 & m2))" "$((i3 & m3))" "$((i4 & m4))"`
```

The error is produce is as follows:

```
192 168 178 15 &  0xff 0xff 0xff 0x00: syntax error in expression (error token is "168 178 15 &  0xff 0xff 0xff 0x00")
```

Anyone here that can tell me why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with quoting the variables fed to the `read` call. If you do this instead (add the quotes):

```
IFS=. read -r i1 i2 i3 i4 <<< "$i"
IFS=. read -r m1 m2 m3 m4 <<< "$s"
```

Everything works again. Still not sure why.

Comment: because IFS is "." for the whole script, so $i is read as: number number number number, but <<< will only get the first one.  If you enclose it in quotes the shell parser stops looking for $IFS chars until end of quotes... always good practice to store OLDIFS first and then restore IFS ASAP

Comment: Thx! Worked like a charm!